# Need regex to ignore everything that is between brackets

Tags: php, regex

Please consider the following string

```
$text = "Dat foo 13.45 and $600 bar {baz:70} and {8}";
```

I need to label all numbers in $text, except for when they are between curly braces. I now have this:

```
preg_replace("/(?<!{)([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)(?!})/","{NUMBER:$0}",$text);
```

which outputs:

```
Dat foo {NUMBER:13.45} and $ {NUMBER:600} bar {baz: {NUMBER:7} 0} and {8}
```

However, the desired output is:

```
Dat foo {NUMBER:13.45} and ${NUMBER:600} bar {baz:70} and {8}
```

where numbers between { and } are ignored, even if they are surrounded by alfanumerical (or other) characters. In other words - how do I need to adjust the regex to completely ignore whatever there is between curly braces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<!{)(?>[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)(?!})
```

[Atomic grouping.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)
And perhaps lookbehind isn't really needed.

Comment: You can't do it in the general case (nested brackets), and even if your brackets can only be one level deep, you'll still need lookbehinds of arbitary length, which php doesn't seem to have.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `/e` in this way:

```
preg_replace("/(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)|{[^}]+}/e", '"$1"?"{NUMBER:$1}":"$0"', $text);
```

Result being:

```
Dat foo {NUMBER:13.45} and ${NUMBER:600} bar {baz:70} and {8}
```

---

An alternative hack like this would work if `{groups}` are always balanced and there are no loose `{}` anywhere:

```
preg_replace("/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?![^{}]*})/", '{NUMBER:$0}', $text);
```

But the first solution is nicer imo.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a simple parser instead:

```
<?php
function parse($str){
    $res = "";
    $tmp_res = "";
    $ignore = false;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $char = $str[$i];
        if ($char === "{" ){
            while ($char != "}" ){
                $res = $res . $char;
                $i++;
                $char = $str[$i];
            }
        }
        if(is_numeric($char)){
            $res = $res . "{NUMBER:$char";
            $i++;
            $char = $str[$i];
            while (is_numeric($char) || $char == '.'){
                $res = $res . $char;
                $i++;
                $char = $str[$i];
            }
            $res = $res . "}" . $char; // add the "}"
        }
        else{
            $res = $res . $char;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

$text = parse("Dat foo 13.45 and $600 bar {baz:70} and {8}");
echo $text;

?>
```

but I must admit that using regex is more elegant!